# Disable scroll behavior modifications by 3rd party scripts in Chrome

Tags: macos, google-chrome, browser, user-experience

How can I prevent 3rd-party scripts included on some websites from changing my mouse / trackpad scroll's behavior? I really don't know intentions of authors that have written scripts that for example [this site](https://gdziestrzelac.eu/) uses... I use latest Google Chrome and MacOS Sierra, thanks in advance!